# Install and configure supervisord on centos 7 to run Laravel queues permanently

Tags: laravel, centos7, supervisord, laravel-queue

I want to use Laravel queue system in my project and I want to run **php artisan queue:work** permanently on server's background, I did some searches about this and I found a command line which can run it even after quit from ssh terminal but It can be down in some cases and can make terrible problems for me. So after a while I found out that there is a package named Supervisord which can restart command even after server is rebooted. So I want to ask someone to help from 0 to 100 step by step how to install Supervisord and configure it on centos 7 and after that set the queue command line. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 99, accepted):

here is how to install and config supervisord on centos 7 to run Laravel queues permanently:

1. `easy_install supervisor`
2. `yum install supervisor`
3. `vim /etc/supervisord.conf` edit section program as following:

> ```
> [program:laravel-worker]
> command=php /path/to/app.com/artisan queue:work 
> process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
> numprocs=8 
> priority=999 
> autostart=true
> autorestart=true  
> startsecs=1
> startretries=3
> user=apache
> redirect_stderr=true
> stdout_logfile=/path/to/log/worker.log
> ```

4. `systemctl enable supervisord` to autorun at start
5. `systemctl restart supervisord` to restart the service

Comment: You assume that people have `easy_install`, in my case, my fresh CentOS didn't. To get it: `yum install -y python-setuptools` then you can proceed (all commands preceded by `sudo` unless you are root...). This doesn't work: `yum install supervisor`: it's installed via easy_install already.

Comment: And what if you have a deployment tool like fabric and want to have multiple scripts/programs in the `.conf` file.

Comment: First run `yum install epel-release`. Supervisor is not available in the default CentOS 7 Repository.

Answer (score 20):

Hopefully this will be of use to someone, this is the process I have been through in addition to @Abdu's answer to get things working on CentOS 7.

**1. Install Supervisor**

`easy_install supervisor`

* If not installed, run `yum install -y python-setuptools` and then `easy_install supervisor`

**2. Prep work**

To get the ideal setup running, you should run the following...

```
# create directory for supervisor logs
mkdir /var/log/supervisor

# create directory for supervisor configs
mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d

# create config directory for supervisor
cat <<EOT >> /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
EOT

# create systemctl service script
cat <<EOT >> /lib/systemd/system/supervisord.service
[Unit]
Description=Supervisor process control system for UNIX
Documentation=http://supervisord.org
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown
ExecReload=/usr/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf $OPTIONS reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=50s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOT
```

Once you've done this, you should now be able to start and stop supervisor using systemctl. To start systemctl, run `systemctl start supervisord`. To view the status of supervisor, run `systemctl status supervisord`.

You can create as many custom configurations as you like under `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`

**3. Enable on system startup**

You should also enable supervisord on startup by running

```
systemctl enable supervisord
```

Comment: Add these to the top of /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf if you get error message "unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file"

`[unix_http_server]

file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)`

Answer (score 2):

On my Bluehost account `systemctl` was not running, but instead `chkserv` was used to monitor and restart processes, so the two answers here did not fully work for me.

Also, I ran into an error with `easy_install supervisor`, since it tried to install the new 4.x.x version, which requires `Python > 2.6`, while 2.6 was the exact version of Python running on my machine.

Here is what worked for me:

1. `yum install -y python-setuptools`
2. `easy_install supervisor==3.4.0`
3. `nano /etc/supervisord.conf` and add

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

[program:laravel-worker]
command=php artisan queue:work --tries=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/queue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/queue.out.log
```

4. `nano /etc/chkserv.d/chkservd.conf`, add the line `supervisord:1`, and then save the file
5. `touch /etc/chkserv.d/supervisord` to create chkservd config file
6. `nano /etc/chkserv.d/supervisord`, add the line `service[supervisord]=x,x,x,service supervisord restart,supervisord,root`, and then save the file
7. `supervisord` will now show up in WHM under `Service Manager`, and `chkservd` will start it and make sure it keeps running, but to manually start it, simply run `supervisord`

For more information on adding a service to `chkservd`, [click here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/TailWatch#4732b1460b8b44d1afa7b627d99bf7bc).