# How to Install / Uninstall Laravel Supervisor (supervisorctl)?

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, supervisord, amazon-linux

I'm using Laravel homestead for dev, but my QA server is on Amazon Linux. Which is CentOS-7 based.

I have installed Supervisor on my Dev the way it is said on [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#supervisor-configuration)

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

And now I'm stack.

It does not say how to uninstall it, and it does not say how to install it on Amazon Linux.

How to Uninstall Laravel Supervisor from Homestead?
And how to install/uninstall it on Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you installed it with `apt-get` then you should be able to remove it with the same package manager.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1144

E.g. with one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove supervisor  # remove the package
sudo apt-get purge supervisor   # remove the package and all configs
```

As for CentOS, try it with `yum`

```
yum install supervisor
yum remove supervisor
```

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-useful-commands.html

Similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322239/3095084

Comment: After installing supervisor the supervisord.conf file missing when I removed supervisor with apt-get remove supervisor and rm rf /etc/supervisor command. But purge worked.