# supervisor laravel doesn't work and started

Tags: php, laravel, centos, queue

my server os is centOS.

```
# pwd
/etc/supervisord.d
```

at this path I created a file:

```
zarsamlog-worker.conf
```

the content of it:

```
[program:laravel-worker-log]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=2
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/storage/logs/supervisor_queue-work.log
```

now:

but this command:

```
#supervisorctl reread
No config updates to processes
```

returns no config updates to processes!

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224707/install-and-configure-supervisord-on-centos-7-to-run-laravel-queues-permanently), I think you must change user to `apache`.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below link, everything you need to configure and run supervisor with laravel, make sure you modify command from

```
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=2
```

to

```
command=php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=2
```

as exactly the way you execute in command line in laravel project
Link : https://vannstudios.com/sending-emails-using-laravel-queues-and-beanstalkd

Comment: --sleep, --tries are arguments passed to laravel queue command, it has nothing do with supervisor service itself.