# Laravel - websockets supervisor run error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpwebsocket

I´ve been searching but all the answers i found didn´t resolve my problem, **my system is centOS** and i have followed [this](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/starting.html#keeping-the-socket-server-running-with-supervisord) instructions with no luck, after that i saw other links, but at some point i´m confused and don´t know what is wrong anymore, so below is what i have done and hopping someone could help me out:

As the instructions say i went to /etc/supervisord.d and created a file called websockets.conf, inside i did this:

```
[program:websockets]
command=/usr/bin/php /home/gynkgo/artisan websockets:serve
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
```

After that, i did the **supervisorctl update** and then **supervisorctl start websockets** this last one returns: **websockets: ERROR (no such process)**. This was when i satrted digging for some other solutions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224707/install-and-configure-supervisord-on-centos-7-to-run-laravel-queues-permanently) so i went to /etc/supervisord.conf, edit the file i putted what is below:(the last version of what i tried)

```
[program:websockets]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/gynkgo/artisan websockets:serve
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
```

but still no luck at all, what am i missing? som epeople say i should have a /etc/supervisor directory but i don´t think that´s the solution, others say that that´s not needed.

Thanks for your time
   Regards

**EDIT:**

After a few tries, i did this **supervisorctl status** and i can see the below:

```
websockets:websockets_00 RUNNING   pid 5137, uptime 0:04:23
```

but when i go to my app i see the error: 
WebSocket connection to (not relevant) failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503

The error above normally disapears if i do php artisan websockets:serve --port=6002, BUT this is the way to force the websockets start, i need the supervisor in order not to do this as you already know.

Comment: I had the same issue with laravel horizon and supervisor. My solution was to run the supervisor under sudo user...

Comment: Well, it turns out the solution was for me to indicate the port, i´m not using the custom port, so that was the problem.